# How can I get rid of these "Overfull \hbox (... too wide) in paragraph at lines 23--26"?

Tags: line-breaking, babel

I have tried \hyphenation{every-where}, - and some more that I don't remember and none works.
These are three sentences where I can three \hbox from

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{refstyle}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel} 
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}

\begin{document}

\section{Sammanfattning}
Den algebraiska metoden utfördes genom att rita in figuren i första kvadranten i ett koordinatsystem och figuren var mätt i SI-enheten centimeter.
För beräkningsändamål i denna rapport undersöks masscentrumet för en figur vars form egentligen är två sammansatta pappersskivor - en halvcirkelskiva sammansatt med en triangelskiva.
Den korrekta x-koordinaten är $9-3,82=\unit[5,18]{cm}$. Därmed ligger tyngdpunkten för halvcirkelskivan i $(5,18;9)$.

\end{document}
```

There is more text that's too wide but you get the point. How do I fix this?

Comment: your example gives the error `! Undefined control sequence.`  please add the definition of `\unit`

Comment: Just remove `\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}`  That makes good linebreaking virtually impossible.

Comment: Omg thank you that worked! @DavidCarlisle

Answer (score 1):

```
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
```

Is preventing hyphenation, that may be useful for some special document formats but for normal text, especially in languages with longish compound words it makes good linebreaking impossible. Just removing fixes the overfull boxes in this case once you fix the udefined command error.

Comment: Yeah, that was the issue, thank you so much!